# How to include FFMpeg library in iphone project

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am using `iFrameExtractor` to extract the frames. But when I clone the project I found that few files from ffmpeg framework was missing.
I tried hard to include the missing file, but was not able to do that..
Can anyone sort out this issue or give me the link of `FrameExtractor` class which contains all the lib files of `FFMpeg`.
I downloaded the project from  [this link](https://github.com/lajos/iFrameExtractor)
but when i open the project i gets the following missing file in the image.!
[This are the missing files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrCbm.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could have a look at the following links

[FFMPEG Compiled Libraries And iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663491/ffmpeg-complied-libraries-and-ios)

[FFMPEG integration on iphone/ ipad project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854190/ffmpeg-integration-on-iphone-ipad-project)

And this tutorial

[FFMPEG Integration](https://github.com/rollmind/ffmpeg-swift-tutorial)

Comment: I tried in many ways but not getting the result... tried to compile as specified in documentation..but not getting any result.
I have downloaded the source code from here https://github.com/lajos/iFrameExtractor but in this project the ffmpeg files are missing. Can you please help me out...

Comment: copy ffmpeg folder your self to the project and then run configure for more details follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003034/installing-ffmpeg-ios-libraries-armv7-armv7s-i386-and-universal-on-mac-with-10