# Installing ffmpeg ios libraries armv7, armv7s, i386 and universal on Mac with 10.8

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

How can I install latest ffmpeg ios libraries armv7, armv7s, i386 and universal on Mac with 10.8?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789827/building-ffmpeg-ios-libraries-for-armv7-armv7s-arm64-i386-and-universal

Comment: please refer this post github repository it will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341770/ffmpeg-ios-7-library/46245639#46245639

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After a couple of days I have made step by step instructions for this install:

FFmpeg Build Instructions MAC 10.8 or better

Copy ffmpeg-2.0.tar.bz2 (https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-1.0.7.tar.bz2, https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and Unzip to Documents folder

Make sure you have the latest Command Line Tools under Xcode >; Preferences >; Downloads >; Components

Install gas-preprocessor

1. Click on the ZIP icon to download https://github.com/mansr/gas-preprocessor.
2. Copy gas-preprocessor.pl to /usr/bin directory.
3. Change permission of gas-preprocessor.pl by setting the privilege to Read & Write for all.

Bug in xcrun starting in version 10.8

open terminal and paste in following command and press enter:

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/"
```

cd to ffmpeg-2 folder and paste in following command and press enter:

```
mkdir armv7
mkdir armv7s
mkdir i386
mkdir -p universal/lib
```

To config armv7s library paste in following command and press enter:

```
./configure --prefix=armv7s --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --enable-avresample --enable-cross-compile --sysroot="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk" --target-os=darwin --cc="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc" --extra-cflags="-arch armv7s -mfpu=neon -miphoneos-version-min=6.1" --extra-ldflags="-arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=6.1" --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a9 --enable-pic
```

> (Note same rule as above: if config fails go to
>   Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
>   and make sure that the sdk folder is iPhoneOS6.1.sdk, if not change
>   the config command to reflect iPhoneOSx.x.sdk and change all targets
>   to x.x)

To build and install armv7s library paste in following command and press enter:

```
make clean && make && make install
```

To config i386 (so simulator will work ) library paste in following command and press enter:

```
./configure --prefix=i386 --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --enable-avresample --enable-cross-compile --sysroot="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk" --target-os=darwin --cc="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc" --extra-cflags="-arch i386" --extra-ldflags="-arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk" --arch=i386 --cpu=i386 --enable-pic --disable-asm
```

> (Note: this is not the same command as the previous two config
>   commands, if you just arrow up to them this will fail)

To build and install i386 library paste in following command and press enter:

```
make clean && make && make install
```

To make universal library ( which is the library added to xcode ) paste in following command and press enter:

```
cd armv7/lib
for file in *.a
do
cd ../..
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -output universal/lib/$file  -create -arch armv7 armv7/lib/$file -arch armv7s armv7s/lib/$file -arch i386 i386/lib/$file
echo "Universal $file created."
cd -
done
cd ../..
```

Comment: [Formatting the code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) will make this easier to read. You can highlight the text and hit ctrl+k or command+k (I think), or click the code button above the text box which looks like `{}`.

Comment: Can you add the support for iOS7?

Comment: I tried using the above instructions with ffmpeg2.2 from https://ffmpeg.org/releases/  and gas-preprocessor from here https://github.com/michaelni/gas-preprocessor
but, i got only static libs files (can i create an executable from this?) also, i don't see the ffmpeg anywhere...? should I have removed the disable-ffmpeg from the configure? 
can you elaborate what it means each parameter? 
if i just want to convert from one audio file format to another? (or merge stereo to mono?) what settings should i use to configure the scripts above? i want the binary output to be as small as possible...

Answer (score 16):

Support universal ffmpeg library for iOS7 and XCode5:

Make sure you have the latest Command Line Tools under Xcode >; Preferences >; Downloads >; Components

Install gas-preprocessor

1. Click on the ZIP icon to download https://github.com/mansr/gas-preprocessor.
2. Copy gas-preprocessor.pl to /usr/bin directory.
3. Change permission of gas-preprocessor.pl by setting the privilege to Read & Write for all.

Download my shell script from: https://gist.github.com/m1entus/6983547

1. Run `sh build-ffmpeg.sh`.

Comment: Awesome, i lost a lot of time for it. :D

Comment: Also check that path to directory, from which you run this script do not contains whitespaces

Comment: I'm getting this error `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.` GCC is apparently depreciated in Xcode5. I'm pretty unsure what to do next.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest Command Line Tools under Xcode >; Preferences >; Downloads >; Components

Comment: I am also getting Joseph Toronto issue, and I seem to be using the latest 5.1.1 command line tools. I can choose from 4.x and 5.x

Answer (score 2):

I needed arm64 support and this script worked for me: https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script

Use

```
./build-ffmpeg.sh arm64 x86_64
```

for iOS 64-bit and simulator architecture. Then copy the contents in the "fat" directory into your Xcode project.

The only modification I made to the script was uncommenting this line:

```
CONFIGURE_FLAGS="$CONFIGURE_FLAGS --enable-avresample"
```

to compile the libavresample library.

Edit: It's not working with armv7 and armv7s however, using iOS 7.1 SDK. If I find a solution I'll post here.

Comment: shouldn't you just add to the command line script the armv7 and armv7s?

Answer (score 1):

For building ffmpeg iOS libraries you can use [this little scripts](https://github.com/wang-bin/build_ffmpeg).

1. Download ffmpeg source
2. Download https://github.com/wang-bin/build_ffmpeg
3. Open terminal and run `export FFSRC=/path/to/ffmpeg`
4. Goto `build_ffmpeg` folder and run: `./ios.sh`
5. After successful building, result will be in `sdk-ios` folder
6. Add include folder and lib folder in your Xcode project