# iFrameExtractor fails to build library for i386 using Xcode5.0 & ios sdk 7.0

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, i386

When configure i386 for iOS simulator 7.0, I got an error in the config.log

Here the configure for i386

`./configure --cc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --as='/usr/local/bin/gas-preprocessor.pl /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk --target-os=darwin --arch=i386 --cpu=i386 --extra-cflags='-arch i386' --extra-ldflags='-arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk' --prefix=compiled/i386 --enable-cross-compile --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --disable-armv5te --disable-swscale-alpha --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-asm --disable-debug`

this is the execute statement

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed
```

error in the config.log

```
ld: building for MacOSX, but linking against dylib built for iOS Simulator file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
C compiler test failed.
```

shall I make any change in the libSystem.dylib file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003034/installing-ffmpeg-ios-libraries-armv7-armv7s-i386-and-universal-on-mac-with-10