# TV audio extracted using ffmeg does not work in iOS (but it works in the simulator)

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, ffmpeg

I can process a TV signal (well I have a .ts video which comes from a TV channel), using ffmpeg but the audio cannot be understood in an iPhone/iPad. The most strange is that the audio (and video) works properly in the simulator (and also in an Android real device, but this is another point), but in a real iPhone/iPad device the video is OK but the audio sounds like a metallic box and nothing can be understood.

I have created the ffmpeg libraries for iOS (I have tried the version 2.0.2 and also the version 2.1.3) using the information provided in the following link:

[Installing ffmpeg ios libraries armv7, armv7s, i386 and universal on Mac with 10.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003034/installing-ffmpeg-ios-libraries-armv7-armv7s-i386-and-universal-on-mac-with-10/19370679#19370679)

The aforementioned link explains how to create the ffmpeg include folders and the universal libraries which I have included into my project (the libraries created are: libavcodec.a, libavdevice.a, libavfilter.a, libavformat.a, libavresample.a, libavutil.a, libswresample.a and libswscale.a).

The sampling frequency used is 48000.

The audio got from ffmpeg is then stored into a buffer and then "inserted" using OpenAL; but, from the same TV content (the same .ts video file) the audio data which is generated from ffmpeg in an iPhone/iPad is totally different from the audio data generated from ffmpeg in the simulator (which can reproduce both the audio and video perfectly).

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I could solved the problem setting the suitable channel audio properties (I had MONO and I have changed to STEREO 16 bits).