# Building ffmpeg iOS libraries for armv7, armv7s, arm64, i386 and universal

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, armv7, i386, arm64

I have seen several scripts to build FFmpeg API for armv7, 7s and i386 but couldn't find anything which would work for armv64 as well. Some of the answers on other threads of this forum suggested to prepare a separate library for arm64 but it does not work well with rest of the architectures. Hence I need a script which can work for all the supported architectures for iOS including armv7, armv7s, armv64 and i386.

Comment: Hey Sandy sorry if I bother you but I have the same problem. I'm looking for the FFMPEG framework (one only file) working with all architectures. Do you have it?

Comment: this is definitely the one to go with !  https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have use below scripts for making FFmpeg build for arm64

https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script

https://github.com/bbcallen/ijkplayer/blob/fc70895c64cbbd20f32f1d81d2d48609ed13f597/ios/tools/do-compile-ffmpeg.sh#L7

You have to add libbz2.dylib and libiconv.dylib framework in your xCode project.

Comment: How to build for ios8 and xcode 6.0 ? Any idea. Please help

Comment: How did you link it in XCode in Swift project? When I try to use any function from ffmpeg, I got an error, e.g.: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "avcodec_register_all()", referenced from:      +[Bridge_ObjectiveC_Cpp run_test_a:] in bridge.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: hello. i can build that script with ffmpeg version 4.0

Comment: Could you please share the useage command to build FFmpeg using https://github.com/bbcallen/ijkplayer/blob/fc70895c64cbbd20f32f1d81d2d48609ed13f597/ios/tools/do-compile-ffmpeg.sh#L7