# How to compile and use FFMPEG in swift OSX?

Tags: swift, macos, ffmpeg

I am new to OSX. I want to convert video format, FFMPEG is needed to do this. Do anyone have any idea about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building ffmpeg iOS libraries for armv7, armv7s, arm64, i386 and universal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789827/building-ffmpeg-ios-libraries-for-armv7-armv7s-arm64-i386-and-universal)