# Installing ffmpeg ios libraries armv7, armv7s, i386 and universal on xCode 6.1 Mac with 10.9

Tags: ios, xcode, ffmpeg, armv7, i386

I have tried many of the solution such as "[Installing ffmpeg ios libraries armv7, armv7s, i386 and universal on Mac with 10.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003034/installing-ffmpeg-ios-libraries-armv7-armv7s-i386-and-universal-on-mac-with-10)"  to compile FFMPEG libraries on MAC for i386 an iphone but i constantly get and error. I guess it could b my xcode and clang version. I have already installed the latest command tools as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why did you not include the actual error?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script can help you build newest FFmpeg 2.5.
https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script

Read the shell script, the code is clean and intuitive, you'll find out that it handles all the things.

Just execute  `./build-ffmpeg.sh`,and you'll get header files and libraries you need.